# Having dynamic proxy with HttpClientFactory implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have `Asp.Net Core WebApi`. I am making Http requests according to [HttpClientFactory pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Here is my sample code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpClient<IMyInterface, MyService>();
    ...
}

public class MyService: IMyInterface
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task CallHttpEndpoint()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "www.customUrl.com");
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }

}
```

I want to implement sending requests through dynamic proxy. This basically means that I might need to change proxy with each request. As for now I find out 2 approuces, non of which seems good to me:

1.Have a static proxy like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpClient<IMyInterface, MyService>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888"),
                UseProxy = true
            };
        });
    ...
}
```

But I can only have single proxy per service in this approach.

2.Dispose `HttpClient` with each request:

```
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888"),
        UseProxy = true,
    };

    using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "www.customUrl.com");
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
```

But in this way I violate HttpClientFactory pattern and it might cause issues to application performance as stated in following [article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Is there a third way where I could change proxy dinamically without re-creating `HttpClient`?

Comment: According to this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests Each time you get an HttpClient object from the IHttpClientFactory, a new instance is returned. But each HttpClient uses an HttpMessageHandler that's pooled and reused by the IHttpClientFactory to reduce resource consumption, as long as the HttpMessageHandler's lifetime hasn't expired. So it is scoped, but with perks.

Answer (score 15):

There is no way to change the any of the properties of `HttpClientHandler` or to assign a new version of `HttpClientHandler` to an existing `HttpClient` after it is instantiated. As such, it is then impossible to have a dynamic proxy for a particular `HttpClient`: you can only specify one proxy.

The correct way to achieve this is to use named clients, instead, and define a client for each proxy endpoint. Then, you'll need to inject `IHttpClientFactory` and pick one of the proxies to use, requesting the named client that implements that.

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyServiceProxy1").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    return new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888"),
        UseProxy = true
    };
});

services.AddHttpClient("MyServiceProxy2").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    return new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8889"),
        UseProxy = true
    };
});

...
```

Then:

```
public class MyService : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyServiceProxy1");
    }

    public async Task CallHttpEndpoint()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "www.customUrl.com");
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you do not know proxy url in advance?

Comment: Then you're really out of luck? In what scenario would you not know something like this in advance though? You may not know *which* proxy to use until runtime, but you'd at least know the possibilities. You configure named clients for each of the possibilities, and then you can easily switch them out at runtime.

Comment: If your app receives this information from an external system (e.g. another app/service, database, etc) at runtime.

Comment: The strategy I'm going for in this situation is to create a new `ServiceCollection` at runtime, add a named `HttpClient` to that then build it into a new `ServiceProvider` from which I will resolve an `IHttpClientFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

I can do that by inheriting from HttpClientHandler:

```
public class ProxyHttpHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private int currentProxyIndex = 0;

private ProxyOptions proxyOptions;

public ProxyHttpHandler(IOptions<ProxyOptions> options)
{
    proxyOptions = options != null ? options.Value : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    UseProxy = true;
}

protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var proxy = proxyOptions.Proxies[currentProxyIndex];
    var proxyResolver = new WebProxy(proxy.Host, proxy.Port)
    {
        Credentials = proxy.Credentials
    };

    Proxy = proxyResolver;

    currentProxyIndex++;
    if(currentProxyIndex >= proxyOptions.Proxies.Count)
        currentProxyIndex = 0;

    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

}

Then I register my `ProxyHttpHandler` and `ProxyOptions` in IoC:

```
public IForksCoreConfigurationBuilder ConfigureProxy(Action<ProxyOptions> options)
{
    Services.AddOptions<ProxyOptions>().Configure(options);
    Services.AddTransient<ProxyHttpHandler>();
    Services.AddHttpClient<IService, MyService>()
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler<ProxyHttpHandler>();

    return this;
}
```

Comment: In second request you can't set proxy again, there is an exception: *This instance has already started one or more requests*