# How I can change configuration of HttpMessageHandler from Polly retry?

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I have the following issue. I have a proxy set. If a request via proxy very slow or has crashed I would like to try again without proxy.

For setting proxy I have the following code in the `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICheckPackagesService, CheckPackagesService>(x =>
{
    x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(IpService.GetIp())
});
```

But I can't imagine what I have to do for sending new one request without proxy (if the previous one has crashed of course!). A fast research in the official documentation gives me nothing.

Please, share your experience for this case. Thank you!

P.S. I use `.NET Core 2.2.401`.

Answer (score 2):

You [cannot change the any of the properties of `HttpClientHandler` or assign a new version of `HttpClientHandler` to an existing `HttpClient` after it is instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574418/).

Therefore you cannot use a Polly retry policy configured via HttpClientFactory to call via a new proxy (Polly policies configured via HttpClientFactory are [applied as a `DelegatingHandler` within `HttpClient`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#how-are-the-polly-policies-applied)).

As stated in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574418/), use named clients defined on IHttpClientFactory instead, and define a named client for each proxy endpoint.