# Adding a SocketsHttpHandler to an HttpClient created via AddHttpClient in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'd like to add a SocketsHttpHandler to an HttpClient that I am creating via AddHttpClient in Startup.cs. The point of that is to be able to inject instrumentation etc. in the HttpClient via a factory.

This does not give me the option to use the constructor of HttpClient, which is where you'd usually add a SocketsHttpHandler.

Also, I don't see any obvious property etc. I can use to add it later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

...aaaand as is traditional I found the answer five minutes later. Never matters how long you look before, does it now?

[How I can change configuration of HttpMessageHandler from Polly retry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708315/how-i-can-change-configuration-of-httpmessagehandler-from-polly-retry)

```
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttpHandler
           {
               MaxConnectionsPerServer = 3,
           })
```